# Acceder a un jQuery Object guardado en una variable

Tags: jquery

Necesito acceder al **jQuery Object** que se guarda como parámetro **editor** y no sé como hacerlo. ¿Alguien me puede explicar que estoy haciendo mal?

```
(function ($) {

    var test = {

    config: {
        editor: $( "#wp-content-wrap" )
    },

    init: function(){
        test.add_button();
        test.enable();
        test.load_events();
    },

    enable: function(){ },
    disable: function(){ },
    load_events: function(){ },

    add_button: function(){
        test.config.editor.before(
            '<div class="builder-tools">' +
            '<a id="switch-button" ' +
            'href="javascript:void(0);">' +
            'Activar' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>')
    }
};

    $(document).ready(function () {
        test.init();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede aquí es que la sentencia `$("#wp-content-wrap")` se ejecuta cuando se carga el `.js`. Esto, puede suceder ANTES de que se termine de cargar la página, por eso no lo encuentra y tiene un valor invalido cuando invocas `add_buttons`.

Para resolverlo puedes mover la inicialización de esa variable dentro del método `init()` ya que este método se invoca *on document ready* el elemento debería estar cargado en el DOM.

Algo así, como puedes ver el botón se inserta entre el titulo y la envoltura:

```js
(function($) {

  var test = {

    config: {},

    init: function() {
      // mueves aqui la inicializacion. 
      test.config.editor =  $("#wp-content-wrap");
      test.add_button();
      test.enable();
      test.load_events();
    },

    enable: function() {},
    disable: function() {},
    load_events: function() {},

    add_button: function() {
      test.config.editor.before(
        '<div class="builder-tools">' +
        '<a id="switch-button" ' +
        'href="javascript:void(0);">' +
        'Activar' +
        '</a>' +
        '</div>')
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    test.init();
  });
  
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>titulo</h1>
<div id="wp-content-wrap">
ENVOLTURA
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Claro, el botón lo agregaba con .before fuera del objeto seleccionado.